# Python (using webdriver to go trough user:password list to login)

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I'm currently looking for some help to basicly login into a website, do 1 click on a button, and then restart the loop with the next user:pass from a .txt file

currently what i have atm:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

#define login
user = raw_input('Enter your username: ')
password = getpass('Enter your password : ')

#define what browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Downloads\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://login.webzen.com/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webzen.com%2Fevents%2Fhalloween-2018%2Ftrick-or-treat&Host=www.webzen.com')

#what boxes to use
username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('UserID')
username_box.send_keys(user)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
password_box.send_keys(password)

#press the actual fcking button
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton')
login_button.submit()

#click candy
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divLoginAfter"]/button')
submit_button.click()
```

Basicly what i want to work out with is how to make an .txt file called accounts.txt with username:password
to make it login , do the script , and then login the rest of the accounts and do the same, any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: Seems like you have the idea already. First you'll want to create a text file with the username:passwords. Then, in this Python script that you already have, you can have it open and read the contents of that text file and pass those values to the steps you have above. Depending on how you format your `accounts.txt`, you can use Python's [read or readline functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Answer (score 1):

I take it that your accounts.txt file looks something like this?

```
user1:password1
user2:password2
etc...
```

In that case you could do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

#define login
user = raw_input('Enter your username: ')
password = getpass('Enter your password : ')

#define what browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Downloads\chromedriver')

with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        user, password = line.split(':')

        driver.get('https://login.webzen.com/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webzen.com%2Fevents%2Fhalloween-2018%2Ftrick-or-treat&Host=www.webzen.com')

        #what boxes to use
        username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('UserID')
        username_box.send_keys(user)

        password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
        password_box.send_keys(password)

        #press the actual fcking button
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton')
        login_button.submit()

        #click candy
        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divLoginAfter"]/button')
        submit_button.click()
```

Comment: is there anyway to loop trough accounts.txt with like a 10~ second delay?

Comment: You can do that by adding `time.sleep(10)` to the part of the code where you want the delay. (+ `import time` at the start of the code)

Comment: thanks that helped! now that i use a txt file to login with it doesnt seem to login, any clue to why?

Comment: Okay, so it worked fine with your `raw_input()` method and now it doesn't? Have you checkt if user and password are getting read correctly from the txt file? (e.g. no spaces, commas, etc.)